# Machine learning terminology

Tags: regression, machine-learning, definition

When we say "**Linear** regression" do we think of the model being linear or the hypothesis function being linear?

When we think only of **linear** regression do we think of the function being linear?

When we say "Logistic regression is also a **linear** regression." do we think of the model being linear?

Comment: This thread might be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regression assumes that there is approximately a linear relationship between a predictor variable $X$ and a *quantitative* response $Y$. Mathematically, we can write this linear relationship as
$Y ≈ β_0 + β_1X$.

In many situations, the response variable $Y$ is instead *qualitative* (e.g. *categorical*). Predicting a qualitative response for an can be referred to as classifying.  Logistic regression is one of classifiers. Logistic regression models the probability that $Y$ belongs to a particular category.
Mathematically, we can write logistic relationship as
$P(X) ≈ β_0 + β_1X$.

In both cases $X$ is liner variable.

See for details **An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R** by G. James, D. Witten, T. Hastie and R. Tibshirani

Comment: Minor quibble: in logistic regression we model a transformation $g(P(Y = 1 \vert X))$ as a linear function of $X$, where $g : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is our link function.

Comment: Linear regression does not assume that $Y$ and $X$ are linearly related. Linear regression models that the response variable is linear with respect to the parameters i.e. $\beta$. $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 {x_1}^2 + \beta_2 \log({x_2})$ is a valid equation for a linear regression model.