# Logistic regression on aggregated counts

Tags: regression, logistic

Normally when we do logistic regression, we would have a dataset something like:

```
   X1 X2 Y
1:  A  3 0
2:  A  4 0
3:  A  3 0
4:  B  4 1
```

(4 observations)

However, for some reasons, I only have the aggregated version:

```
   X1 X2 count Y_count
1:  A  3     2       0
2:  A  4     1       0
3:  B  4     1       1
```

(i.e. a summary table. e.g. 2 records with `X1 = A and X2 = 3` but the number of `Y = 1` is 0)

Now, I understand that I can simply replicate and do the logistic regression normal way; but my question is whether I can simply use the summary table to do logistic regression (potentially in R). Any implications?

There're other posts of similar questions: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242175/difference-between-logistic-regression-and-linear-regression-on-aggregated-datas).
Also I'm aware that "weights in logistic regression differs from ... weights in linear regression) ([ref](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/logistic.html))

Comment: The answer to this already exists in the answer to this question: 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259502/in-using-the-cbind-function-in-r-for-a-logistic-regression-on-a-2-times-2-t

Comment: For people who have the similar questions, there are three types of data formats logistic regression can use: long form, wide form, weighted form

Comment: @LeGeniusll, that's addressed in the previous answer.