# How to model the factors affecting decision making (buying a car)?

Tags: r, regression, anova, modeling, linear

I would like to determine the factors affecting a persons decision to buy a new car. Upon inspecting the data, I have found that things such as:

- Number of people in the household
- Cost of tax
- Income
- Gender
- Occupation

all are significant in decision making.

I would like to build a model to quantify how a decision is affected, if these parameters change. For example, how would a persons decision be affected if their income rose by £10,000 per annum, or they had a new baby?

I need to build some sort of linear model. I would like to end up with a list of coefficients for each significant variable, which will give me what I need, but wondered what approach I needed to take.

The data I am using has been split into two, and is binary (have bought a new car - 1, or have not bought a new car - 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can model this with a multiple logistic regression. Standard logistic regression models the *probability* of a dependent binary variable as a function of one or more independent variables. The [logistic tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic?sort=votes&pageSize=50) has a number of relevant questions that may help you, such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29325/121522).