# Ho do I determine the probability of price reversals using linear regression?

Tags: regression, mean-absolute-deviation

In the screenshot, you will see the daily prices of Nasdaq. Each candle has a High, Low, Open and Close price.
I have drawn a regression line with a 2 standard deviation channel on either side.
How would I go about determining the following odds:

Price reversing back to the mean from the top of the channel
Price reversing back to the mean from the bottom of the channel

Here is the relevant data in CSV format:

> ```
> Date,open,high,low,close
> 2020-04-22,8638.04,8791.67,8584.55,8606.75
> 2020-04-23,8606.75,8786.69,8503.14,8773.93
> 2020-04-26,8773.93,8904.59,8736.59,8824.04
> 2020-04-27,8824.04,8953.96,8662.47,8707.38
> 2020-04-28,8707.38,9128.59,8707.38,9128.17
> 2020-04-29,9128.17,9154.75,8866.86,8879.61
> 2020-04-30,8879.61,8888.91,8682.93,8727.01
> 2020-05-03,8727.01,8838.2,8568.02,8820.48
> 2020-05-04,8820.48,9030.75,8810.19,8945.63
> 2020-05-05,8945.63,9068.2,8890.4,8957.83
> 2020-05-06,8957.83,9137.67,8942.08,9129.77
> 2020-05-07,9129.77,9246.73,9115.09,9225.91
> 2020-05-10,9225.91,9346.54,9127.77,9289.57
> 2020-05-11,9289.57,9354.5,9048.46,9050.96
> 2020-05-12,9050.96,9212.14,8886.47,9022.94
> 2020-05-13,9022.94,9113.27,8856.21,9097.25
> 2020-05-14,9097.25,9156.71,8933.83,9103.21
> 2020-05-17,9103.21,9369.66,9103.21,9324.09
> 2020-05-18,9324.09,9424.65,9291.39,9305.1
> 2020-05-19,9305.1,9502.52,9280.79,9499.07
> 2020-05-20,9499.07,9515.22,9355.88,9363.9
> 2020-05-21,9363.9,9422.59,9246.58,9410.25
> 2020-05-24,9410.25,9541.35,9395.05,9534.01
> 2020-05-25,9534.01,9608.78,9376.65,9416.38
> 2020-05-26,9416.38,9512.9,9177.67,9446.79
> 2020-05-27,9446.79,9569.72,9324.69,9462.54
> 2020-05-28,9462.54,9586.35,9376.22,9580.78
> 2020-05-31,9580.78,9609.06,9454.77,9596.79
> 2020-06-01,9596.79,9673.83,9509.08,9661.21
> 2020-06-02,9661.21,9730.72,9638.96,9692.7
> 2020-06-03,9692.7,9744.5,9574.55,9645.42
> 2020-06-04,9645.42,9847.5,9603.96,9810.66
> 2020-06-07,9810.66,9902.49,9748.95,9884.84
> 2020-06-08,9884.84,10006.7,9813.53,9963.26
> 2020-06-09,9963.26,10157.12,9960.27,10088.48
> 2020-06-10,10088.48,10108.41,9585.13,9621.5
> 2020-06-11,9621.5,9849.63,9495.38,9646
> 2020-06-14,9646,9816,9381.75,9811.77
> 2020-06-15,9811.77,10014,9797.8,9969.67
> 2020-06-16,9969.67,10059.42,9926.92,9998.25
> 2020-06-17,9998.25,10041.38,9879.25,10003.09
> 2020-06-18,10003.09,10125.67,9929.69,9932.92
> 2020-06-21,9932.92,10147.67,9856.86,10134.79
> 2020-06-22,10134.79,10309.42,9985.74,10190.49
> 2020-06-23,10190.49,10255.2,9941.56,10029.03
> 2020-06-24,10029.03,10120.51,9899.8,10109.29
> 2020-06-25,10109.29,10134.14,9837.73,9880.49
> 2020-06-28,9880.49,10010.65,9743.03,9999.65
> 2020-06-29,9999.65,10184.18,9953.2,10151.46
> 2020-06-30,10151.46,10321.62,10088.89,10268.39
> 2020-07-01,10268.39,10433.51,10259.41,10360.82
> 2020-07-02,10360.82,10400.9,10320.4,10338.29
> 2020-07-05,10338.29,10626.21,10338.29,10610.1
> 2020-07-06,10610.1,10706.55,10517.89,10538.77
> 2020-07-07,10538.77,10685.05,10517.73,10683.92
> 2020-07-08,10683.92,10786.46,10572.29,10735.73
> 2020-07-09,10735.73,10854.72,10637.74,10850.22
> 2020-07-12,10850.22,11070.48,10574.11,10610.96
> 2020-07-13,10610.96,10705.54,10371.63,10656
> 2020-07-14,10656,10778.78,10563.94,10701.21
> 2020-07-15,10701.21,10710.39,10488.15,10546.97
> 2020-07-16,10546.97,10681.67,10535.74,10636.56
> 2020-07-19,10636.56,10972.65,10558.93,10959.53
> ```

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: if you want help from stats community you need to explain and clearly define your terms: price reversal, mean, channel etc. these are very TA domain specific terms. alternatively, you can go to https://quant.stackexchange.com/ site. you may not like what they'll tell you though. TA is nonsense, in my opinion, but it can be great to establish this on your own by actually back testing different TA techniques.

Comment: Why linear regression and not logistic regression?

Comment: I don't know @Tim. Why would I use one over the other? I'm here to learn.

Comment: @Grantx linear regression can predict anything between $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so it is a pretty poor choice if you need to predict probabilities. Logistic regression predict values between 0 and 1, so probabilities.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. You should make that the answer and I will give you the credit.

Comment: Average regression Paper
Research Link
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/374200106_Calculation_of_price_graphs_reversal_point_from_average_regression_lines_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regression is a model that can predict values in unrestricted domain, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. If you want a regression model to predict probabilities, then the to-go model is [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) that restricts the outputs to $[0, 1]$ range.

For more details see other questions tagged as [logistic-regression](/questions/tagged/logistic-regression), for example the [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression) thread.

Answer (score 0):

See Dr Abdul Rahim Wong's paper on Calculation of price graphs reversal point, from average regression lines method.
Link https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/ytz7pyg8y9/1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/354718)