Should the linear regression of a transformed $y$ (sigmoid $y$) be identical to the transformation (sigmoid) of the responce
Should the sigmoid $(1/(1+e^{-y}))$ of the predictand $\hat y$ of the linear model be identical to the linear regression of the sigmoid $y$. The Python example below demonstrates linear regression of the sigmoid of binary data and the sigmoid transformation of response $\hat y$. They are close but not identical (see the green and red lines/curves). Yet, in general, should the transformation of a response $\operatorname{sigmoid}(\hat y)$ be the same as the regression of the sigmoid ($\operatorname{sigmoid} (y) = a\cdot x + \varepsilon)$. Please keep in mind that I did not use the linear generalized model.
Thanks

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy.special import expit

# plotting the inverselogit. 
#plt.figure();plt.plot(expit(np.arange(100)))

x = np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

##############
# inverse logit (sigmoid) of linear regression 
linearReg = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
y_hat_linear = x * linearReg.coef_ + linearReg.intercept_
# inverse logit (sigmoid)  # 1/(1+exp(-y))
inverselogit_linear = expit(y_hat_linear) 
print(linearReg.coef_)
print(linearReg.intercept_)

#############
# linear regression of inverse logit (sigmoid)
linearlogReg = LinearRegression().fit(x,expit(y))
y_hat_linearlog = x * linearlogReg.coef_ + linearlogReg.intercept_
print(linearlogReg.coef_)
print(linearlogReg.intercept_)
###################
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y_hat_linear,label='linear regression')
plt.plot(x,inverselogit_linear,label='sigmoid of response (OLS)')
plt.plot(x,y_hat_linearlog,label='response (OLS)  of sigmoid')
plt.legend()


It looks as if every value of your response variable is either $0$ or $1.$  Are you using ordinary least squares to fit a sigmoid curve?

Think about what the transformation of the data does to the part of y that comes from the added noise term, compared to adding a noise term to the transformed mean.

@MichaelHardy my $y$ data is binary y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

I suspect that developing a refined understanding of logistic regression would be the best way to address this question.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325 to begin with.
